# Kendo Grid - Horizontal Scrollbar does not appear when there is no data

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo UI Grid as listed below. The horizontal scroll bar is appearing when there are records. But it does not appear when there are no records. How to bring the scroll – bar even if there are no records.

**Grid**

```
     <div class="GridSearch">

     @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.TransactionHistoryModel>()
    .Name("TransactionHistroyGrid")
     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.UserId);
            model.Field(p => p.Comment).Editable(true);
        })

        .PageSize(25)
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("TransactionHistorySearch_Read", "Home")
            .Data("additionalData")
            )
     )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {

        columns.Command(c => c.Custom("Edit").Click("editDetails")).HeaderTemplate("Action").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).Width(90);
        columns.Command(c => { c.Custom("Save").Click("saveDetails"); c.Custom("Cancel").Click("cancelDetails"); }).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(p => p.UserId).Filterable(false).Title("UserID").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).Width(90);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Status).Filterable(false).Title("Status").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).Width(70);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Reviewed).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox'  class='chkbx' type='checkbox' disabled='disabled' />").Filterable(false).Title("Reviewed").Width(80);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProjectCaseNumber).Filterable(false).Title("Project Case #").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CostPage).Filterable(false).Title("CP Page #").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).Width(90);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ItemID).Filterable(false).Title("Item ID #").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).Width(90);
        columns.Bound(p => p.TypeOfChange).Filterable(false).Title("Type of Change").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ChangeDescription).Filterable(false).Title("Change Description").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).Width(120);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedOnEnd).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Filterable(false).Title("Created On").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).Width(85);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UpdatedOnEnd).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Filterable(false).Title("Updated On").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).Width(85);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Comment).Filterable(false).Title("Comment").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" }).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden();

        currentIndex++;
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable(sorting => sorting.AllowUnsort(false))
    .Scrollable()
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:325px;" }).Events(e => e.DataBound("onRowDataBound"))

)
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.GridSearch {
    float: left;
    width: 960px;
    height: 325px;
    padding: 2px 0 20px 0px;
    clear:left;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet. Please add below OndataBound event in your grid.

```
function onDataBound(arg) {
    if (arg.sender._data.length == 0) {
        var contentDiv = this.wrapper.children(".k-grid-content"),
        dataTable = contentDiv.children("table");
        if (!dataTable.find("tr").length) {
            dataTable.children("tbody").append("<tr colspan='" + this.columns.length + "'><td> </td></tr>");
            if ($.browser.msie) {
                dataTable.width(this.wrapper.children(".k-grid-header").find("table").width());
                contentDiv.scrollLeft(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
function dataBound(e) {
if (this.dataSource.view().length == 0) {
  //insert empty row
  var colspan = this.thead.find("th").length;
  var emptyRow = "<tr><td colspan='" + colspan + "'></td></tr>";
  this.tbody.html(emptyRow);

  //workarounds for IE lt 9
  this.table.width(800);
  $(".k-grid-content").height(2 * kendo.support.scrollbar());
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this CSS to force the horizontal scroll bar to be enabled all the time:

```
.k-grid-content {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: While that shows the scrollbar, the scrollbar can't be used because it doesn't have the proper width information.

Answer (score 2):

I have used noRecords: true option, and other solutions doesn't work for me (label appears not in grid-container, but below).

Have found other solution- set width of noRecords label thru kendo templates equal to grid width:

```
    noRecords: {
        template: '<div style="width: #=this.table.width()#px">No records found.</div>'
    },
```

it has side effect- labels width wont changes dynamically when grid width is changed

Comment: This works for me, and I like this solution the best anyway, I feel like there should always be a message when there are no records so that the user knows that he or she is not just seeing a squashed grid.

Answer (score -1):

Use following code. It works like charm :)

```
$('.k-grid-header, .k-grid-content').wrapAll('<div class="grid-wrapper" style="overflow: scroll" />');
```

Comment: This does answer the question - the scroll bar does *appear*, however it is greyed out and you can't actually use it to scroll.